# Reselect checkboxes after Post in included file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have page Search.asp (code below). And Filtered.asp which include Search.asp.

```
             <%
                Dim CheckForCheckboxes
                CheckForCheckboxes = Request.form("chkBoxes")
                response.write "CheckForCheckboxes" & CheckForCheckboxes
                %>    
                <div  id="ExSearch" name="ExSearch" >
                    <script>
  // on page load check if this page called from POST and have passed checkboxes to select                  
                    var str = '<%=CheckForCheckboxes%>'; // {"Make[]":["AIXAM","CADILLAC","JEEP"],"selCountry[]":["5","4","8"]}
                    if (!str || str.length === 0) {} else {
                        var Checked = JSON.parse(str); 
// alert works here
        // This one not work
                        $("#ExSearch").find('div.list input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox],div.selector select').each(function () {
// alert do not work here
                            var $el = $(this);
                            var name = $el.attr('name');
                            var value = $el.attr('value');
                            if (Checked[name] && Checked[name].indexOf(value) !== -1 ) {$el.prop('checked', true);}
                        });
                    };
                    
     // from here function which select checkboxes and hold them in hidden input field before submit, on submit pass this object with form               
                    $(function() {
                    
                        $('div.list input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').on('change',onValueChange);     
                        $('div.selector select').on('change', onValueChange);
                    
                        function onValueChange() {      
                                var Checked = {};
                                var Selected = {};
                                
                            // Hold all checkboxes
                                $('div.list input[type=radio]:checked, input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                                    var $el = $(this);
                                    var name = $el.attr('name');
                                    if (typeof (Checked[name]) === 'undefined') {Checked[name] = [];}
                                    Checked[name].push($el.val());
                                });
                            // Hold all dropdowns
                                $('div.list select').each(function () {
                                    var $el = $(this);
                                    var name = $el.attr('name');
                                    if (!!$el.val()) {Selected[name] = $el.val();}
                                });
                    
                        // Put all together to POST 
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/Search.asp',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: $.param(Selected) + "&" + $.param(Checked),
                                dataType: 'text',
                                success: function (data) {
            // Put response data to page and reselect checkboxes, this works good
                                    $("#ExSearch").html(data).find('div.list input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox],div.selector select').each(function () {
                                        var $el = $(this);
                                        var name = $el.attr('name');
                                        var value = $el.attr('value');
                                        if (Checked[name] && Checked[name].indexOf(value) !== -1 ) {$el.prop('checked', true);}
                                        if (Selected[name]) {$el.val(Selected[name]);}
                                    });
    // Hold converted object to string values
                                    $("<input type='hidden' value='' />").attr("id", "chkBoxes").attr("name", "chkBoxes").attr("value", JSON.stringify(Checked)).prependTo("#ajaxform");
                                }
                            });
                        };
                    });
                    
                    </script>   
                    
                    <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="Filtered.asp" method="POST">
                    </form>
                    </div>
```

So If page Search.asp starting I check if object passed via form post method, and if passed I need to select checkboxes which is in this object.
So I create object, then I convert it to string with Json.stringify and then catch form post string and convert back to object with JSON.parse

So everything look ok but checkboxes is not selecting and no errors appears.

What now is wrong?

Comment: did you check, if it works without that if contion?

Comment: No, but i trying to put alert mesages in after each statment and alert do not appear but alert appear before each statment

Comment: what is the format of data which has been returned from the server?

Comment: Data format is converted object to string and then back from this string to object, so `str = {"Make[]":["AIXAM","CADILLAC","JEEP"]}`

Comment: If your returned data is not in html format, you just cant use this code $("#ExSearch").html(

Comment: code $("#ExSearch").html( return data in html format!!! It is ok and happins after checkboxes is clicked. But on first load i need to select checkboxes wich was selected and Posted before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note what your  code loading first and then loading your all divs so `$("#ExSearch").find(` cant find any checkboxes.

Try to put your `<script></script>` code after `</form>`